# How to use python pool.imap_unordered efficiently?

Tags: python, pool, unordered

I'm using python multiprocessing imap.unordered with big expectations.
However, my processes are in deep sleeping waiting for I/O.

```
numofSimulations=10
chromNamesList=['chr1', 'chr2', 'chr3', 'chr4', 'chr5', 'chr6', 'chr7', 'chrX', 'chr8', 'chr9', 'chr10', 'chr11', 'chr12', 'chr13', 'chr14', 'chr15', 'chr16', 'chr17', 'chr18', 'chr20', 'chrY', 'chr19', 'chr22', 'chr21', 'chrM']
sim_nums = range(0, numofSimulations+1)
sim_num_chr_tuples=((sim_num,chrLong) for sim_num in sim_nums for chrLong in chromNamesList)

for arrayList in pool.imap_unordered(prepare_data_fill_arrays, (fillInputList(simNum,chrLong,x,y,z,a,b,c) for simNum,chrLong in sim_num_chr_tuples),chunksize=1):

    print('Worker pid %s in accumulate' %str(os.getpid()))
    array1 = arrayList[0]
    array2 = arrayList[1]
    accumulateArray(accumulatedArray1, array1)
    accumulateArray(accumulatedArray2, array2)
```

In this pseudocode, I call imap_unordered for each simNum and chrLong pair.
I submit for the same simulation number with varying chromosomes so that they won't try to read the same chrom input file at the same time.

`fillInputList` just fills inputList.

`prepare_data_fill_arrays` reads chromosome based files and fills arrays.

However since imap_unordered are submitted in an order of different chromosomes at the same time, why processes are waiting for?

And why

> Worker id XXXX in accumulate

is written before any comment is written in prepare_data_fill_arrays?

Comment: Multiprocessing won't help speed up I/O. That's dependent on your I/O source.

Comment: My point is that, I would expect 24 processes to be running on (sim1,chr1), (sim1,chr2) ... (sim1,chrX). Since each chrom has a different input file.  Now only 1 or 2 processor are running.

Comment: Does "only 1 or 2 processes are running" mean 24 processes exist but most are sleeping or that only a couple of processes exist? Do the processes actually complete and produce a result or do they seem to die with no explanation? Have you tried doing this with just a normal `imap` call to ensure your functions aren't hitting an exception? If so, you can try wrapping the entire body of your `prepare_data_fill_arrays` in a `try`/`except` block to catch exceptions in the workers.

Comment: Also, just because your iterable has 24 items it doesn't necessarily mean 24 processes will be spawned to handle them. By default, pools won't spawn more processes than you have cores.Worker processes may handle multiple tasks before they're replaced or joined.

Comment: @skrrgwasme There are 28 processes in the cluster. Since I'm calling imap.unordered(,chunksize=1), I'm expecting at least 24 processes to be running. e.g.: for (sim1,chr1) (sim1,chr2) (sim1,chr3) ... (sim1,chrX)

Comment: I would first suspect that there are some messages or exceptions occurring in some of the workers that isn't being propagated to the main process or stdout. First confirm that all of the code works without using multiprocessing. If that passes, add logging to the functions that execute in subprocesses that will write messages to a file. Put a lot of context and progress messages in those logs so you can see everything happening in them. Also wrap the whole function bodies in a try/except block that will capture any exception and dump the exception info and stack trace to the logs if it occurs.

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with Python multiprocessing. If I remember correctly, output and exceptions *should* be propagated to stdout and the main process, but I definitely had some problems with silent worker process failures. Explicitly catching exceptions and logging them to a file guaranteed I could see that happening.